# Trying to convert a variable in PHP to an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've got a variable that I've retrieved from an API call, and am trying to convert the output in to an array.  Below is an example of the output:

```
{"id":"4335416","linkId":4335416,"title":"Website 1","slashtag":"1","destination":"http://website1.com","createdAt":"2017-09-20T12:10:56.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-12-01T13:59:35.000Z","status":"active","clicks":722,"lastClickDate":"2018-01-28T15:47:21.000Z","lastClickAt":"2018-01-28T15:47:21.000Z","isPublic":false,"shortUrl":"url.st/1","domainId":"abc123","domainName":"url.st","domain":{"id":"abc123","ref":"/domains/abc123","fullName":"url.st","active":true},"https":false,"favourite":false,"creator":{"id":"321cba","fullName":"user123","avatarUrl":"https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/"}},
{"id":"4335402","linkId":4335402,"title":"Website 2","slashtag":"2","destination":"http://website2.com","createdAt":"2017-09-20T12:09:29.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-12-01T13:58:56.000Z","status":"active","clicks":234,"lastClickDate":"2018-01-28T13:44:29.000Z","lastClickAt":"2018-01-28T13:44:29.000Z","isPublic":false,"shortUrl":"url.st/2","domainId":"abc123","domainName":"url.st","domain":{"id":"abc123","ref":"/domains/abc123","fullName":"url.st","active":true},"https":false,"favourite":false,"creator":{"id":"321cba","fullName":"user123","avatarUrl":"https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/"}},
{"id":"4335375","linkId":4335375,"title":"Website 3","slashtag":"3","destination":"http://website3.com","createdAt":"2017-09-20T12:07:23.000Z","updatedAt":"2017-12-20T18:43:17.000Z","status":"active","clicks":111,"lastClickDate":null,"lastClickAt":null,"isPublic":false,"shortUrl":"url.st/3","domainId":"abc123","domainName":"url.st","domain":{"id":"abc123","ref":"/domains/abc123","fullName":"url.st","active":true},"https":false,"favourite":false,"creator":{"id":"321cba","fullName":"user123","avatarUrl":"https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/"}}
```

I would like it to create an array within an array, as below:

```
$myArray = array( array( id => "4335416", 
                      linkId => 4335416,
                      title => "Website 1",
                      slashtag => "1",
                      destination => "http://website1.com",
                      ...
                    ),
               array( id => "4335402", 
                      linkId => 4335402,
                      title => "Website 2",
                      slashtag => "2",
                      destination => "http://website2.com",
                      ...
                    )
               array( id => "4335375", 
                      linkId => 4335375,
                      title => "Website 3",
                      slashtag => "3",
                      destination => "http://website3.com",
                      ...
                    )
             );
```

Completely stumped on this...  Although my head has been spinning all day trying to do stuff :(

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: `json_decode($str, true);`

Comment: In your paste of what the API returns, you are missing the open and close square braces. If this indeed is how the API returns the data, then just using json_decode alone won't work. You'll need to first add the square braces before using that function.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to an array with:

`json_decode($myArray, true);`

The second argument `true` will make it an associative array which has the named keys from your JSON data.

[json_decode documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `json_decode('APIcallValue', true)`

[PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

This API response appears to be JSON.

Try doing:

```
$myArray = json_decode($api_response, true);
```

Where $api_response is the API response variable

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that guys...

```
json_decode($api_response, true)
```

worked perfect.  How simple when you know all the different commands!  lmao.  Should've just posted here first off...  Saved me a couple of hours...

Thanks again

Comment: You should choose an answer not post a copy... :P

Comment: Sorry...  I didn't see anything that said to select an answer...  Oops :-/

Comment: no biggie, it's a grayed out `check-mark` beside each submitted answers

Comment: ah nvm its been marked as duplicate...